# Unable to insert data into database if I select only one day in a week

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert data into database by checking the days in a week but I am unable to insert if I check only one day in a week, if I check two or more days I am able to insert.

```
     <?php
           //other parameters
            $days_only = $_REQUEST['days_only'];
```

using an array to split days in a week

```
            $day_array = explode(",",$days_only);
            $count_sample = count($day_array);
            if($count_sample==1) {
                $in_sample='('.$days_only.')';
            }
            elseif($count_sample>0) {
                $in_sample="('".str_replace(",","','" , $days_only)."')";
            }
                    $test='IN'.$in_sample;
            $sth = "SELECT e_id FROM `schedule` WHERE
            user_id = '$user_id' AND
            date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' AND
            (
            TIME(start_time) >= '$start_time' AND
            TIME(start_time) <= '$end_time' OR
            TIME(end_time) >= '$start_time' AND
            TIME(end_time) <= '$end_time' 
            ) AND days_only $test";
            
            $res = $db->prepare($sth);
            $res->execute();
            $count = $res->fetchAll();
            if ($count) {
                echo "すでにスケジュールが登録されています";
                } else {
                    
                  for($i = strtotime($start_date); $i <= strtotime($end_date); $i +=86400 ){
                    
                        
                       $date =  date("Y-m-d", $i);
                       $days_only = date('l', $i);
            
                       switch ($days_only) {
                        case 'Monday': $days_only = "月"; break;
                        case 'Tuesday': $days_only = "火"; break;
                        case 'Wednesday': $days_only = "水"; break;
                        case 'Thursday': $days_only = "木"; break;
                        case 'Friday': $days_only = "金"; break;
                        case 'Saturday': $days_only = "土"; break;
                        case 'Sunday': $days_only = "日"; break;
                    }
                       
                       echo "$date";
                       echo "$days_only";
                      if (in_array($days_only,$day_array)){
```

query for inserting into database

```
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "wrong";
                        }
                    }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: What error are you encountering? Can you share a dump of `$days_only` in the working and the failing scenario?

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks for the response, I am unable to insert data when I select only one day of a week

Comment: @El_Vanja When I select more than two from the array $days_only I am able to insert Query successfully. Is there any thing I have to change while just check box only one particular day from $days_only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
if( $count_sample==1 ) {
   $in_sample='('.$days_only.')';
}
```

The string that you're passing in `$days_only` is not being escaped here, but it is when the `$count_sample` value is greater than one. The above code will give you something like this: `(金)`

Perhaps you can replace the two outermost single-quotes with a double-quote and drop the concat period:

```
$in_sample= "('$days_only')";
```

Or you can replace a good bit of code with a single `implode()`:

```
if ( $count_sample > 0) {
    $in_sample="('" . implode("','", $days_only) . "')";
}
```

Be sure to remember to add validation to your inputs before sending this to the database, otherwise you leave yourself open to SQL injection

Comment: Thank you so much @matigo, it worked I really appreciate your help and advice.